# Kaminari paginating nested children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, kaminari

I have a Ruby-on-Rails application (Ruby 2.3.2) and running the Kaminari gem for pagination. I've run into a situation where I need dynamic pagination through a child association. In example:

An application that allows people to look up books in a library. There's a `library` class, which `has_many: :books`. The library controller has this:

```
# LibrariesController
expose_decorated :library
expose_decorated :books

def show
  self.library = Library.find(params[:library_id])
  self.books = library.books.page(params[:books_page])
end
```

And the library/show.html.slim:

```
/- # library/show.html.slim
a name='library_books_list'
= render layout: 'books/index', locals: { books: books }
  = paginate books, param_name: 'books_page', params: { anchor: 'library_books_list' }
```

And this works just fine. However, I need to update the application so that all the books are sorted by publisher. So, now my library model has this:

```
# Library model
has_many :publishers
has_many :books, through: :publishers
```

I'm formatting the library #show page to list out all of the publishers, and within each publisher block list off the paginated books. I need each publisher block to paginate independently, which I know requires unique paginating `param_name` for each publisher block. What follows is semi-pseudocode of what my libraries controller and show page should be.

```
# LibrariesController
expose_decorated :library
expose_decorated :publishers
expose_decorated :books # The PublishersController is never called, so this has to be here

def show
  self.library = Library.find(params[:library_id])
  self.publishers = library.publishers # Doesn't have to be paginated
  # Something like this?
  self.publishers.each do |p|
    p.books.page(params[:"books_page_#{p.id}"])
  end
```

And the libraries show page:

```
/- # library/show.html.slim
- publishers.each do |p|
  a name="library_books_list_#{p.id}"
  = render layout: 'books/index', locals: { books: p.books }
    = paginate p.books, param_name: "books_page_#{p.id}", params: { anchor: "library_books_list_#{p.id}" }
```

The publisher controller is never called, so I can't paginate on there. The above doesn't work, because it doesn't give the publishers' books the correct variables to paginate (undefined method `total_pages'). Trying to add the pagination on the view page also doesn't work:

```
= render layout: 'books/index', locals: { books: p.books.page(params[:"books_page_#{p.id}"]) }
  = paginate p.books, param_name: "books_page_#{p.id}", params: { anchor: "library_books_list_#{p.id}" }
```

and

```
= render layout: 'books/index', locals: { books: p.books }
  = paginate p.books.page(params[:"books_page_#{p.id}"]), param_name: "books_page_#{p.id}", params: { anchor: "library_books_list_#{p.id}" }
```

both fail the same way: `undefined method 'page' for #<PaginatingDecorator`. It should be noted that the 'books/index' doesn't call the books controller either; it's just a view page that prints out relevant information of the items passed in.